# Apex Pmd : Apex classes should escape variables merged in DML query (rule: Security-ApexSOQLInjection)apex pmdApexSOQLInjection

Tags: apex, pmd

**I have referred pmd ruleset but could not find the exact solution for this,please help?**

```
opportunityListOH = new list<opportunity>();
        String query = 'Select Id, Name, StageName,Freeze__c,Freeze_Date__c,Owner.id,Owner.Name FROM Opportunity Where '+dateVal + Fixed + ' AND StageName = \''+ StageOptionsValueOH + '\''; 
        opportunityListOH = Database.query(query); <-- Error on this line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `String.escapeSingleQuotes(str)` for each one of your variables in query - `dateVal Fixed StageOptionsValueOH` because otherwise it could lead to Security vulnerability